How to access elements of Array
I am trying to access an element in the following json response from an API call via
foilResponse.data.products.edges[0].totalInventory

however no matter what variation of the above I use everything shows as undefined. When I query the endpoint with postman i get the full array returned, is there something I need to configure within Node?
{
  data: { products: { edges: [Array] } },
  extensions: {
    cost: {
      requestedQueryCost: 3,
      actualQueryCost: 3,
      throttleStatus: [Object]
  }
}


Are you sure the items in edges have a totalInventory? Usually edges has as .node in there like .edges[0].node.totalInventory.

You may to verify if there is appropriate data in the array.

hmm, it may be thats its failing to infer the type definition. try:
interface IFoilResponse {
  data: { products: { edges: Record<string, any>[] };
  extensions: { 
    cost: {
      requestedQueryCost: number;
      actualQueryCost: number;
      throttelStatus: Record<string, any>;  
   }
}

const foilResponse: IFoilResponse = data;
console.log(foilResponse.data.products.edges[0].totalInventory);

Though, assuming you are not using typescript and are using javascript you code try:
(foilResponse.data.products.edges[0] as Record<string, any>)?.totalInventory;

though a cleaner way would be:
Object(foilResponse.data.products.edges[0])?.totalInventory;

sorry, for the rapid fire approach but, I figure that a few options would be better. though, looks like you've asked this question before here on stackOverflow but, looks the data can be accessed adding the node property ex: foilResponse.data.products.edges[0].node.totalInventory
